# How can I arrange a string by its alphabetical order using only While loop and conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given the String `"aaababababab"` (Only `'a'` or `'b'` allowed):
How do I order the string alphabetically to be like `"aaaaaaabbbbb"` by only using a while loop?

This is my current attempt:

```
word = "ababababaabab"
wordfixed = ""
i = 0

while i < len(word):
    if word[i] == "a":
        wordfixed += "a"
        i += 1

    elif word[i] == "b":
        wordfixed += (word[i])
        i += 1

print(wordfixed)
```

But **it simply prints the original word** back. How can I get it to print the desired output?

Comment: How about `''.join(sorted(word))`

Comment: Instead of one variable `wordfixed` you could use a separate variable for all "a"s and all "b"s and concatenate them at the end.

Comment: @WasifHasan the question states (twice) that only `while` is allowed

Answer (score 1):

Using your current idea, you could just append to one end or the other depending on the value of the letter. This would allow `a` to accumulate at the start and `b` to build off the end.

```
word = "ababababaabab"
wordfixed = ""
i = 0

while i < len(word):
    if word[i] == "a":
        wordfixed = word[i] + wordfixed 
    elif word[i] == "b":
        wordfixed = wordfixed + word[i]
    i += 1


print(wordfixed)
# aaaaaaabbbbbb
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create two "helper" variables: one to accumulate the `a`s, and one for the `b`s. Then in the end just concatenate them in the right order:

```
word = "ababababaabab"
wordfixed = ""
wordfixed2 = ""
wordfixed3 = ""
i = 0

while i < len(word):
    if word[i] == "a":
        wordfixed2 += "a"
    elif word[i] == "b":
        wordfixed3 += "b"
    i += 1

wordfixed = wordfixed2 + wordfixed3
print(wordfixed)
```

I think that's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because you add the letter that you currently have at the end - so it will be the same afterwards.

You can instead count amount of `'a'`'s while looping through the string once (for loop would be better suited but while can be used as well) - then print the remaining `'b'`:

```
word = "ababababaabab"
lw = len(word)
i = 0 
a_s= 0  
while i < lw:
    if word[i] == 'a':
        print("a", end="")  # dont end the line quite yet
        a_s += 1 
    i += 1

# print b's for remaining wordlength minus printed a's
print('b' * (lw-a_s))
```

or better with for loop:

```
a_s = 0
for letter in word:
    if letter == "a":
        a_s +=1
        print(letter, end="")
print('b' * (lw-a_s))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll go with @Mark_Meyer solution but if you don't really need to use only the while loop, here is an easy way to go :

```
word = "ababababaabab"
print(word.count('a')*'a' + word.count('b')*'b')
# aaaaaaabbbbbb
```

Comment: The question states that only `while` loop is allowed and for the lack of `while` in your answer I don't think it really answers the question. This could, however, go as a useful comment for an alternative solution